# Admob banner ad is somewhat cut off in Android app

Tags: java, android, admob, ads

So I have added a `SMART_BANNER` banner at the end of the layout.

but as you can see in image2, sometimes the bottom of the banner is a little cut off and the banner is like not fully displayed.

Is this a problem? Or it is normal in test ads but in real ads it won't happen?

[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/geaSO.jpg)

[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yC0Lb.jpg)

```
  <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
                    android:id="@+id/ad_id"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
                    app:adUnitId="@string/id">

                </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

Comment: Please post the layout file.

Comment: I have edited the question with the ad attributes

Comment: This might be a creative issue then, do live ads also have this issue?